# Unable to return value from a fetch call when doing it via connectAsync

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following where everything works fine getting proper data from externalData.

But when it comes to allData, I am getting the data correctly based on the response

being logged. But the response doesn't seem to be returned. When I use that allData value, 
it is coming out as undefined. Whereas the other value which is called via iguazu works fine.

```
import React  from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connectAsync } from 'iguazu';
import { queryResource } from 'iguazu-rest';

export const MyComponent = ({
  allData,
  externalData,
}) => {

  const output = outputMapper(
    externalData, // has correct data
    allData, // is undefined. Why?
  );

  return (
    <div>
    {/* Not relevant component being returned */}
    </div>
  );
};

export function loadDataAsProps({ store: { dispatch }, ownProps }) {
  return {
    allData: () =>
      fetch('url.com')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response); // prints correctly.
          return response; // but this value doesn't seems to return.
        })
        .catch(e => {
        }),
    externalData: () => dispatch(queryResource({ // works fine. externalData has data as expected
      path: 'sample.com',
    })),
  };
}

const connected = compose(
  // there is other mapping here omitted to keep it clean
  // so do need the compose.
  connectAsync({ loadDataAsProps })
);

export default connected(MyComponent);
```

Comment: `connectAsync()` [expects](https://github.com/americanexpress/iguazu/blob/6aacf6e3d8318e5c45caeb274e6e871f57bdd99e/src/connectAsync.jsx#L31) a `loadDataAsProps` param. Try calling it like this: `connectAsync({ loadDataAsProps: load })`

Comment: @Vitalii thanks. But same outcome. Also amended the above method to read as loadDataAsProps which is also sam outcome.